# how to get the value after certain Prefix in android?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string like abc-5,xyz-9,pqr-15 Now,I want to get the value only after "-" So, how can i get that value..and i want this value in String Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int pos = string.indexOf('-');
String sub = string.substring(pos);
```

If you have multiple values in each string, you'll have to split it first (using `split` method). For example:

```
String[] array = string.split(',');
String[] values = new String[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    values[i] = array[i].substring(arrays[i].indexOf('-'));
```

Now you have the values in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
String string = "abc-5,xyz-9,pqr-15";
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String val1 = parts[0].split("-");
.....
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

I would use `split` on your string.

```
String str = "abc-5,xyz-9,pqr-15";
String[] arr = str.split(",");

for (String elem: arr) {
    System.out.print(elem.split("-")[1] + " : ");  // Will print - `5 : 9 : 15`
}
```

or with `Regular Expression` like this: -

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("-(\\d+)").matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String newString= oldString.substring(oldString.indexOf('-'));
```